# What does "SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file" "problems getting password error" indicate in Nginx error log?

Tags: ssl, https, nginx, openssl, private-key

I'm trying to set up SSL on Nginx. It doesn't work, and I am getting the following error in the error log, which is getting passed up from the OpenSSL library which nginx was compiled with. I don't know what that library is, but it's version 0.8.54 of nginx, and I installed it using apt-get on Ubuntu Linux.

```
2012/02/21 07:06:33 [emerg] 4071#0: 
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/exequias/certs/exequias.com.key") failed (SSL: 
error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password error:
0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read error:140B0009:SSL routines:
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)
```

I have ensured that the file permissions on the private key file are not stopping nginx from reading it. It is an RSA private key, generated with `openssl rsa`.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got it... the private key file used with nginx must *not* have a passphrase. I removed the passphrase and it worked.

Comment: I don't remember -- I may just have generated a new private key with `openssl`, and left off the passphrase.

Comment: @CrossleSong `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and don't enter a passphrase to generate a key without passphrase.

Comment: You can definitely use key files with a passphrase with Nginx! See [sudoz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632189/452775).

Answer (score 67):

Remove the key pass phrase:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out newkey.pem
```

If the certificate and the key are together:

```
openssl rsa -in mycert.pem -out newcert.pem
openssl x509 -in mycert.pem >>newcert.pem
```

Source: http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#key-removepass

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was in R'lyeh. You saved my sanity.

Comment: You're welcome :-) I hear you. It's two years since I wrote this answer and now I don't remember a thing about this :D #insanityrealized

Answer (score 21):

Because you generate the .crt file with a passphrase, so you need to specify the same passphrase for your .key and .crt file in Nginx conf like this

```
server {
    ssl_password_file /path-to-your-passphrase/ssl.pass;
}
```

See [Nginx Doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file)

Or if you don't need the passphrase for your cert file, just use `ssh-keygen` tool to generate the file as following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Comment: @JosephCoco Yep, you are right. I need to edit my answer.

Comment: Perfect :thumbsup:

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit old now, and nginx actually supports passphrase asking at startup since at least version 1.2. But the issue is still relevant because this capability has been removed from debian in the latest release, version 8 with nginx 1.6. The reason is that passphrase input hasn't been implemented in the systemd script for nginx, while it has been for apache. Launching nginx manually simply works, and it's not too a problem since manual intervention is required anyway, there's no use of systemd here.

Reference: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,262900,262931#msg-262931